# storing a large list of key/value pairs in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make myself a chrome extension that collects data from pages and fills my popup (list of items) and for this i need to save stuff.

I want to have CRUD operations for a large list of items (pageUrl, pageSelectedText, pageLinks, Date,..) etc for my popup list.

I know i have html5 localStorage and chrome's storage.sync.set but for these storages i could not find examples on how to store multiple key/values and also i risk the quota exceeded when the list gets large?

Question: if i store for example in key "pageUrl" then obviously i would override that key each time?

Guess i would need id's like in ordinary databases where i have id=1,2,...n
What would be the best practise for storing an increasing list of key/value pairs?

Can i use a browser database like indexedDB and if so, can i still use some chrome's sync feature with indexedDB or do i need my own sync service on a webserver?

ps. How do you think the "pocket" (formerly: read it later) extension does it's savings?

I would like to use the simplier solutions so if i can store multiple key's for the same thing with storage.sync.set would it be a nice solution to generate the keys myself like:

keyName = pageUrl + Id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IndexedDB in a Chrome extension no problem. But if you want Chrome to sync data you have to use `chrome.storage.sync`. Pocket has their own API server they store data with.

Comment: thx. so as i see it the best option would be to use google app engine and implement my own syncro there, because storage.sync from chrome APi has obvious limitations for size and writing..

Comment: What do you think about my question above, how would i differentiate multiple keys of the same value, like "pageUrl" because i want to store multiple page url's and show in the popup. Should the best practise be to generate the keys with id's in there names? I have searched trough most of the examples and didn't found enough examples regarding storage.